# Custom scrapy xml+rss exporter to S3

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to create a custom xml feed, that will contain the spider scraped items, as well as some other high level information, stored in the spider definition. The output should be stored on S3.

The desired output looks like the following:

```
<xml>
  <title>my title defined in the spider</title>
  <description>The description from the spider</description>
  <items>
    <item>...</item>
  </items>
</xml>
```

In order to do so, I defined a custom exporter, which is able to export the desired output file locally.

**spider.py:**

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dmoz'
    allowed_domains = ['dmoz.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/']
    title = 'The DMOZ super feed'

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield item
```

**exporters.py:**

```
from scrapy.conf import settings

class CustomItemExporter(XmlItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = kwargs.pop('title', 'no title found')
        self.link = settings.get('FEED_URI', 'localhost')
        super(CustomItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_exporting(self):
       ...
       self._export_xml_field('title', self.title)
       ...
```

**settings.py:**

```
FEED_URI = 's3://bucket-name/%(name)s.xml'
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'custom': 'my.exporters.CustomItemExporter',
}
```

I'm able to run the whole thing and get the output on s3 by running the following command:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -t custom
```

or, if I want to export a json locally instead: `scrapy crawl -o dmoz.json dmoz`

But at this point, I'm unable to retrieve the spider title to put it in the output file.

I tried implementing a custom pipeline, which outputs data locally (following numerous examples):

**pipelines.py:**

```
class CustomExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_feed.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b') 
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CustomItemExporter(
            file,
            title = spider.title),
        )
        self.exporter.start_exporting()
```

The problem is, the file is stored locally, and this short circuits the FeedExporter logic defined in feedexport.py, that handles all the different storages.
No info from the FeedExporter is available in the pipeline, and I would like to reuse all that logic without duplicating code. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

1. get rid of the pipeline.
2. Override scrapy's FeedExporter

   **myproject/feedexport.py:**

   ```
   from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import FeedExporter as _FeedExporter
   from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import SpiderSlot

   class FeedExporter(_FeedExporter):

       def open_spider(self, spider):
           uri = self.urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
           storage = self._get_storage(uri)
           file = storage.open(spider)
           extra = { 
               # my extra settings
           }
           exporter = self._get_exporter(file, fields_to_export=self.export_fields, extra=extra)
           exporter.start_exporting()
           self.slot = SpiderSlot(file, exporter, storage, uri)
   ```

   *All I wanted to do was basically to pass those extra settings to the exporter, but the way it's built, there is no choice but to override.
   To support other scrapy export formats simultaneously, I would have to consider overriding the dont_fail settings to True in some scrapy exporters to prevent them from failing*
3. Replace scrapy's feed exporter by the new one

   **myproject/feedexport.py:**

   ```
   EXTENSIONS = {
       'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter': None,
       'myproject.feedexport.FeedExporter': 0,
   }
   ```

   *... or the 2 feed exporters would run at the same time*